# FAMOpen -1 connection error: Connection refused (fam_fd=-1)

Tags: ubuntu

As I used FAM to monitor file sys, it failed at FAMopen function at some computers, which makes me confused.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fam.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        FAMConnection famCon;
        int ret = FAMOpen(&famCon);
        std::cout << "ret1 = " << ret << "\n";
        if(ret < 0) {
            perror("FAM connection error");
        }   
        int fam_fd = FAMCONNECTION_GETFD(&famCon);
        std::cout << "fam_fd = " << fam_fd << "\n";

    //    ret = FAMOpen(&famCon);
    //    std::cout << "ret2 = " << ret << "\n";


        return 0;
    }
```

FAMOpen always return -1 （failed）：

> ret1 = -1 
>   FAM connection error: Connection refused
>   fam_fd = -3

Anyone matches this problem before? Or what problems may make such errors happen?